# how to ignore FB/Other social contacts in address book when counting contacts

Tags: facebook, cocoa-touch, ios6, abaddressbook, abperson

I need to get the count of only my local contacts from Address Book, not any social networks. How do i filter other contacts out programmatically?

In another words, how Contacts application shows separately iCloud groups and Facebook group. How do they filter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do that is to use the Contact app and tab the groups button in the top left - at the bottom you will see your facebook contacts that you can de-select.

This will then give an accurate count of your contacts:-)

Note that this will not delete them, just filter them out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I asked about Address Book API that I can use to do it.

Comment: Ah Sorry missed that part of the question:-)